# How to display a map by selecting the correct WMTS layer id?

Tags: c#, maui, arcgis

I am trying to display a map in my MAUI desktop application utilizing an open API with the following method:

```
private async Task LoadWMTSLayer(bool uriMode)

    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new map.
            Map myMap = new Map();

            // Get the basemap from the map.
            Basemap myBasemap = myMap.Basemap;

            // Get the layer collection for the base layers.
            LayerCollection myLayerCollection = myBasemap.BaseLayers;

            // Create an instance for the WMTS layer.
            WmtsLayer myWmtsLayer;

            // Define the Uri to the WMTS service.
            Uri wmtsUri = new Uri(" https://avoin-karttakuva.maanmittauslaitos.fi/avoin/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?api-key=myAPI");
            //Uri wmtsUri = new Uri("https://avoin-karttakuva.maanmittauslaitos.fi/avoin/wmts/1.0.0/taustakartta/default/WGS84_Pseudo-Mercator/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D.png?api-key=myAPI");


            // Define a new instance of the WMTS service.
            WmtsService myWmtsService = new WmtsService(wmtsUri);

            // Load the WMTS service.
            await myWmtsService.LoadAsync();

            // Get the service information (i.e. metadata) about the WMTS service.
            WmtsServiceInfo myWmtsServiceInfo = myWmtsService.ServiceInfo;

            // Obtain the read only list of WMTS layer info objects, and select the one with the desired Id value.
            WmtsLayerInfo info = myWmtsServiceInfo.LayerInfos.Single(l => l.Id == "taustakartta");

            // Create a WMTS layer using WMTS layer info.
            myWmtsLayer = new WmtsLayer(info);
          
            // Add the WMTS layer to the layer collection of the map.
            myLayerCollection.Add(myWmtsLayer);

            // Assign the map to the MapView.
            MyMapView.Map = myMap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Sample error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
```

This is the layer I am trying to access from the xml:

```
<Layer>
<ows:Title>Taustakartta</ows:Title>
<ows:Identifier>taustakartta</ows:Identifier>
<Style isDefault="true">
<ows:Identifier>default</ows:Identifier>
</Style>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<TileMatrixSetLink>
<TileMatrixSet>ETRS-TM35FIN</TileMatrixSet>
</TileMatrixSetLink>
<TileMatrixSetLink>
<TileMatrixSet>WGS84_Pseudo-Mercator</TileMatrixSet>
</TileMatrixSetLink>
<ResourceURL format="image/png" resourceType="tile" template="https://avoin-karttakuva.maanmittauslaitos.fi/avoin/wmts/1.0.0/taustakartta/default/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}.png"/>
</Layer>
```

When I run the app all I get is a grid. However, it shows a map when I use the documentation URI  `Uri wmtsUri = new Uri("https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best");`

The xaml:

```
<Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#fff" Margin="4" BorderColor="#fff">
            <!-- Dummy location content -->
            <!--<Label Text="Location:" />-->
            <Grid >
                <esriUI:MapView x:Name="MyMapView" />
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
```

Additionally, when I use the second URI from the first code snippet I get a `401` even though I am using a valid API key. Can someone please tell me the approach I should take to solve this problem?

Edit:
I made the following changes on the first code snippet to make sure that the `info` gets the Layer neede `taustakartta`. Here is the updated function:
private async Task LoadWMTSLayer(bool uriMode)

```
{
    try
    {
        // Create a new map.
        Map myMap = new Map();

        // Get the basemap from the map.
        Basemap myBasemap = myMap.Basemap;

        // Get the layer collection for the base layers.
        LayerCollection myLayerCollection = myBasemap.BaseLayers;

        // Create an instance for the WMTS layer.
        WmtsLayer myWmtsLayer;

        // Define the Uri to the WMTS service.
        Uri wmtsUri = new Uri(" https://avoin-karttakuva.maanmittauslaitos.fi/avoin/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?api-key=myAPIKey");
        //Uri wmtsUri = new Uri("https://avoin-karttakuva.maanmittauslaitos.fi/avoin/wmts/1.0.0/taustakartta/default/WGS84_Pseudo-Mercator/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D.png?api-key=myAPIKey");


        // Define a new instance of the WMTS service.
        WmtsService myWmtsService = new WmtsService(wmtsUri);

        // Load the WMTS service.
        await myWmtsService.LoadAsync();

        // Get the service information (i.e. metadata) about the WMTS service.
        WmtsServiceInfo myWmtsServiceInfo = myWmtsService.ServiceInfo;
        WmtsLayerInfo info;
        foreach (WmtsLayerInfo layerInfo in myWmtsServiceInfo.LayerInfos)
            {
                if (layerInfo.Id == "taustakartta")
                {
                    info = layerInfo;
                    break;
                }
            }

        // Obtain the read only list of WMTS layer info objects, and select the one with the desired Id value.
         info = myWmtsServiceInfo.LayerInfos.Single(l => l.Id == "taustakartta");


        // Create a WMTS layer using WMTS layer info.
        myWmtsLayer = new WmtsLayer(info);

        // Add the WMTS layer to the layer collection of the map.
        myLayerCollection.Add(myWmtsLayer);

        // Assign the map to the MapView.
        MyMapView.Map = myMap;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Sample error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
    }
}
```